# How to do multiple clients with 1 server?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, client-server, java-io

This is my server. I'm using JFrame by the way. Actually I have many pc's when I run the server in pc 1 then the client that is on the pc 2 and pc 3. The pc 3 client connect but the server cannot receive the message. While the pc 2 client has connected.

```
 package server;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;

public class FrmServer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ServerSocket providerSocket;
Socket connection=null;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
String message;

//To run the connection
public void run(){
```

for the connection

```
    try{
        providerSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
        msgArea.append("Waiting for connection....");
        connection = providerSocket.accept();

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();

        in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        sendmessage("Connection is successful...");

        while(true){
           message = (String)in.readObject();

           if(!message.isEmpty())
               msgArea.append("\nClient: "+message);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

}

public void sendmessage(String msg){

    try{
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
        msgArea.append("\nServer: "+msg);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

/**
 * Creates new form FrmServer
 */
public FrmServer() {
    initComponents();
}

private void btnSendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    sendmessage(txt.getText());
} 
public static void main(String args[]) {
FrmServer s = new FrmServer();
    s.setVisible(true);
    s.run();

}
```

Client

```
package client;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FrmClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Socket requestSocket;
ObjectInputStream in;
ObjectOutputStream out;
String message;
/**
 * Creates new form FrmClient
 */
public FrmClient() {
    initComponents();
}

public void run(){

    try{
        requestSocket = new Socket("10.99.225.12",9090);
        msgArea.append("Connected to the server...");

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();

        in = new ObjectInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());

        while(true){
           message = (String)in.readObject(); 

           if(!message.isEmpty());
               msgArea.append("\nServer: "+message);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

}

public void sendmessage(String msg){

    try{
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();

        msgArea.append("\nClient: "+msg);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

}

private void btnSendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    sendmessage(txt.getText());
}  
private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    try{
        sendmessage("Got to go.. Goodbye!");
        in.close();
        out.close();
        requestSocket.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

} 
public static void main(String args[]) {
FrmClient c = new FrmClient();
    c.setVisible(true);
    c.run();
}
```

Comment: You tagged the q multithreading. So you obviously already know the answer ...

Comment: At the end of this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) you can find a simple example how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make for each socket (client) a thread, and handle them.

For so far I see, there's only **one** connection made, as you initialise `connection` only once.

You could make a list, with all sockets and write/read from/to their input/output stream.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dedicated thread to listen for a connection continuously.

Once you accept a connection, create two threads for each accepted connection, one for reading incoming data, another one to write data to the socket.

Here is a simple modification of your code, although it can be written in a better way.

1. Make your JFrame class implements Runnable.

   ```
   public class FrmServer extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable
   ```
2. implements run method in your JFrame class

   ```
   @Override
   public void run() {
       while (true) {
           try {
               msgArea.append("Waiting for connection....");
               connection = providerSocket.accept();
               new ConnectionWriter(connection, msgArea).start();
               new ConnectionReader(connection, msgArea).start();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               System.err.out(ex);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a thread to write to a socket

   ```
   public class ConnectionWriter extends Thread {

       ObjectOutputStream out;
       Socket connection;
       JTextArea msgArea;

       public ConnectionWriter(Socket connection, JTextArea msgArea) {
           this.connection = connection;
           this.msgArea = msgArea;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
               out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
               out.flush();
               sendmessage("Connection is successful...");
           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
           }
       }

       public void sendmessage(String msg) {

           try {
               out.writeObject(msg);
               out.flush();
               msgArea.append("\nServer: " + msg);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.err.println(e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create a thread to read from a socket.

   ```
   public class ConnectionReader extends Thread {

       ObjectInputStream in;
       Socket connection;
       JTextArea msgArea;

       public ConnectionReader(Socket connection, JTextArea msgArea) {
           this.connection = connection;
           this.msgArea = msgArea;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
               in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
               while (true) {
                   String message = (String) in.readObject();

                   if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                       msgArea.append("\nClient: " + message);
                   }
               }
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               System.err.out(e);
           }
       }

   }
   ```